# Diminuir script ou trocar por um código em PHP, ajuda

Tags: php, javascript

Bom dia, se não for incomodar, necessito de ajuda com um script que fiz em java.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data, horaAtual, tempoLimite;
    var clique = 0;

    function data() {
        data = new Date();
        horaAtual = data.getSeconds();
        tempoLimite = horaAtual + 10;
    }

    var gravado = new Array();
    gravado.push(tempoLimite);

    function add() {
        clique = 1;
    }

    function calcular() {
        data;
        document.body.onmousedown = add;
        var numero = parseInt(gravado[0]);
        var data2 = new Date();
        var horaAtual2 = data2.getSeconds();
        if((numero - horaAtual2) < 5){
            alert('Tempo limite atingido!');
        } if(clique == 1){
            var data3 = new Date();
            var horaAtual3 = data3.getSeconds();
            var tempoLimite3 = horaAtual3 + 10;

            gravado.splice(0);
            gravado.push(tempoLimite3);
            clique = 0;
            alert(gravado[0]);
        }
    setTimeout(calcular,1000);
    }
</script>
```

Bom, deixa eu explicar um pouco dessa bagunça, é um Script muito simples, ele recebe a Hora atual do computador e pega apenas os segundos, após isso ele gera uma outra variável pega os segundo mais uma vez e adiciona mais 10s e grava em uma Array (Tive que fazer isso, porque sempre que atualizava ele pegava um novo valor em vez de manter o antigo).

Depois ele faz uma subtração do valor da Array com os segundos atuais para que seja gerada uma mensagem quando o tempo chegar ao limite que no caso é de 5s.

Outra função é que se caso o usuário clique em um dos botões do site ele gere uma nova contagem do tempo e adicione mais 5s atualizando o array.

Agora vão me perguntar o porque dessa bagunça, vamos lá, eu preciso de um sistema de TimeOut, para que o usuário tenha um tempo x  para estar no site se caso estiver ocioso e que por causa dessa inatividade ele deslogue, mas se caso ele entrar em atividade dentro do tempo x o site gere os mesmos x tempo para que o usuário não seja deslogado.

Preciso diminuir esse código, simplificar essa bagunça ou troca-lo por um script em PHP, tentei fazer em PHP mas começou a ficar complexo de mais pra mim, não achei certas funcionalidades, foi um fracasso!

Espero que entendam minha dúvida, agradeço desde já, obrigado!

Comment: Bem complicado. Em vez de tentar explicar seu código, acho que seria melhor vc explicar o que quer fazer, com clareza, assim poderíamos propor um código melhor e mais simples. Não entendi o porquê de pegar a hora atual do computador, se, pelo que entendi, basta ver se o cara fica 5s inativo. Pra isso a hora do computador não influi em nada.

Comment: Então seria melhor fazer uma contagem regressiva? Falando dessa forma me sinto meio dislexo, qual seria a melhor maneira de criar um código em que o usuário fique um tempo x ocioso no site e caso ele não clique em nenhum botão seja deslogado?

Comment: Depende o que vc considerar ocioso. Fazer scroll, por exemplo, sem clicar em nada, o cara está ocioso?

Comment: Deixei minha resposta mais equilibrada, não acho que seria ocioso ao estar ativo olhando algo na página, mas não sei como utilizar isso em códigos, poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 2 escutadores e chame a função para deslogar desta forma:

```js
deslogado = false;
function desloga(){
   temporiza = setTimeout(function(){
      alert("Deslogado por inatividade");
      deslogado = true;
   }, 5000);
}

document.body.onmousedown = function(){
   clearTimeout(temporiza);
   if(!deslogado){
      desloga();
   }
}

document.body.onscroll = function(){
   clearTimeout(temporiza);
   if(!deslogado){
      desloga();
   }
}

window.onload = desloga;
```

```html
Clique na página ou faça scroll para não ser deslogado em 5 segundos
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

Comment: Muito mais prático e sem muita redundância, muito obrigado pela clareza e paciência em me dar uma aula de lógica, estou começando ADS e ainda estou meio perdido em certos aspectos da programação, sabe me dizer se esse código fica tão seguro em javascript quanto em PHP em relação a compatibilidade?

Comment: @netoschneider Em php vc não vai conseguir fazer isso, pq o php roda no servidor. O que vc pode fazer é guardar uma SESSION com o horário que o cara logou e depois enviar um ajax pra verificar o tempo de inatividade. Mas isso é outra questão. Não deixe de marcar a resposta com ✔. Se quiser depois eu ajudo com a parte do PHP.

Comment: @netoschneider Exclui a resposta que vc postou tb porque é contra o regulamento do site postar edições da pergunta ou comentários no campo de resposta. Abs!

Comment: Tudo bem, já apaguei, muito obrigado pelas informações, só por dar essa dica da área de PHP e simplificar meu código com essas dicas importantes já me ajudou de mais até, obrigado pelo apoio e boa noite!